# Highcharts X-range. Columns of maximum height

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have highchart x-range type. And I need make columns on this chart with max height. 
Now I show you, how I did it.

https://jsfiddle.net/ArtemSkliar/ub0mhLr2/1/

```
.highcharts-partfill-original {
  height: 100%;
}
```

How you can see, I just update styles for class name called 'highcharts-partfill-original'.

But this solution has one flaw. When I want to export this chart, of course, my custom style does not pull up, and the chart is displayed on the exported file not as I need it.

Please help me to solve this problem.

I tried to play with the options of the chart, and with export options. But it did not help me.

I also found in highchart export module 'resources' params https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview
intended just for custom styles, but he refuses to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's cool idea to achieve that. However, I would use simple plugin to achieve this natively:

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.xrange.prototype, 'drawPoint', function(proceed, point) {

    // Simply modify height of the point:
    point.shapeArgs.height = point.series.yAxis.height - point.shapeArgs.y;

    return proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

  });
})(Highcharts);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bt0y934m/

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks a lot for your help!